# jQuery Mobile unchecked if another element is checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checked

I cannot find the mistake here.

jsFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/bagofmilk/472s8/

I simply want to make it so that:

Scenario 1:
    - User checks a bunch of checkboxes.
    - User checks "I hate fruit"
    - All other checkboxes are un-checked except for "I Hate Fruit"

Scenario 2:
    - User already has "I Hate Fruit" checked.
    - User clicks any other checkbox.
    - The checkbox "I Hate Fruit" is automatically unchecked.

HTML:

```
<div data-role='page' id='page1'>
 <section id='squestion2c' class='quest'>
    <h4>What are your Favorite Fruits?</h4>
    <span style='font-style:italic;'> (check all that apply)</span>

    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='apples' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='apples'>Apples</label>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='bananas' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='bananas'>Bananas</label>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='canteloupe' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='canteloupe'>Canteloupe</label>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='strawberries' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='strawberries'>Strawberries</label>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='raspberries' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='raspberries'>Raspberries</label>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='blueberries' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='blueberries'>Blueberries</label>
    <input type='checkbox' class='fruits' id='hatefruit' name='favoriteFruits' data-mini='true'/>
    <label for='hatefruit'>I Hate Fruit</label>
  </section>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fruits").change(function() {
    if ($('#hatefruit').is(":checked")) {
       $('.fruits').prop('checked', false);
       $('#hatefruit').prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
       $('#hatefruit').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile. Secondly, when you check/uncheck a checkbox or radio button problematically, you need to re-style it using `.checkboxradio("refresh")`.

To bind event, use `pageinit` as it fires once per page, this will ensure you dont add multiple listeners to the same item.

Since all checkboxes has the same `.fruits`, check if the *checked* one has *hatefruit* id. Accordingly, check/uncheck the rest of checkboxes.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function () {
    $(".fruits").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && this.id == "hatefruit") {
            $('.fruits').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
            $(this).prop('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        } else {
            $('#hatefruit').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/avDJ9/)**

Comment: Awesome. It works and I learned something new. That makes a lot of sense using pageinit. Thanks!